# How to include field names in AWS query output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run a describe-instances query to get the ImageId, State.Name, KeyName, and LaunchTime of my instance. I have this query

```
    aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[ImageId, State.Name, KeyName, LaunchTime][0]"  --filters Name=tag-value,Values=**my_value**
```

which is giving me the results I want as far as the values, like so:

```
    "ami-01ur90418...",
    "running",
    "**my_tag_value**",
    "2022-01-19T02:41:34+00:00"
```

I want it to include the name of the field in the output though, like so:

```
    "instance_id": "ami-01ur90418...",
    "state": "running",
    "keyName": **my_tag_value**",
    "LaunchTime": "2022-01-19T02:41:34+00:00"
```

How can I update my query to include those values?

Answer (score 0):

How about you try this.
`aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].{Instance_id: InstanceId, KeyName: KeyName, LaunchTime: LaunchTime, State: State.Name}[0]" -'filters Name=tag-value,Values=**my_value**`